# Variable not being set to correct value

Tags: c++, debugging, variables

I am making a Tic Tac Toe game. At the end of the game if one of the two human players wins, it is supposed to say "Player [1 or 2] has won!" It does this by checking what value ('X' or 'O') the winning row/column/diagonal is and corresponds it to what player it is (player 1 chooses X or O as their symbol). However, it ALWAYS thinks that player 1 has won regardless of who actually won.

Weird thing is, I can have the program cout both playerwon and BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1") and player_won will ALWAYS output 'X' and BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1") will output the correct answer, whether it's X or O.

Question: Why is player_won always being set to X? It is supposed to be set to the value of the player who won, but for some reason it is always set to X even if the winning player's value is 'O'.

If you need more information, please let me know. Thanks for your help!

```cpp
char player1_mark;
char player_won;

class Boardstatus
{

char A1;

public:

    char getsquarestatus( string square )
{
  // enumerator basically changes A1-C3 to a number 1-9
  // not an actual enumerator, just a function
    int squarenumber = enumerator( square );
    switch ( squarenumber )
    {
    case 1:
        return A1;
        break;
    }
}
private:

    //This function acts similar to an enumerator, but instead returns a number 1-9 based
    //on what string x is entered so that the switch cases in get and setsquarestatus will
    //function properly (they require int or char to work)
    int enumerator( string x )
    {
       if ( x == "A1" )
       {
           return 1;
       }
    };

    bool checkwin( Boardstatus& BSTAT)
    {
        //Row 'A' checkwin
        if (BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1")!= ' ' && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A2") && BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A2")==BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A3"))
        {
            //****This is where something is wrong****
            player_won = BSTAT.getsquarestatus("A1");
            return true;
        }
    }

int main()
{         
Boardstatus BSTAT;  
if ( player_won = player1_mark )
    {
        cout << "Player 1 has won!";
    }
else
    {
        cout << "Player 2 has won!";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand what you're asking. What is your question?

Comment: Why is player_won always being set to 'X' regardless of who actually won the game? It is supposed to be set to the value of the winning player, and player 1 picks which either X or O as their player mark. Sorry, I will edit my OP to be more specific.

Comment: Your `enumerator` method looks very odd. You do realize that your program will fail if you pass in any value other than `"A1"`, since you don't return a value otherwise?

Comment: I know,  It's something I will change. There are a few error checks I am going to add to the program. It actually doesn't fail if players input an odd value, just skips their turn, but nonetheless it's still something I will iron out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `if ( player_won = player1_mark )` is setting the value of `player_won`

You need `==` for comparison, not assignment.

Comment: Of course. A simple oversight that I can't believe I missed. It now works. Thanks!

Comment: Full compiler warning usually catch this, as do lint tools.

Comment: Sure thing. I was going to do it but it said I had to wait 5 minutes for some reason.